# Verify that opencl binary has been stripped of intermediate data

Tags: opencl, elf

I am following [the steps in this knowledge base article](http://developer.amd.com/knowledge-base/?ID=115) to strip off code and intermediate info from an opencl binary. How do I verify that this information has indeed been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make sure that the following sections are absent from the resulting binary:

- .source
- .llvmir
- .amdil

For that, run `readelf -a stripped_kernel.bin | grep section`, replacing "`section`" with the name of each of the sections above. If the binary has been properly stripped, `grep` should produce no result.

Comment: Another question: is there anything else I can do to prevent someone from hacking my binary, once these elf sections have been removed ? Any other security measures I can take?

Comment: Thanks, by hacking, I mean reverse-engineering the binary.  So, stripping .source, .llvimir and .amdil will only make it harder to do this, never impossible?